# Storing NFC tags on Android

Tags: android, nfc

can nexus s be used as an NFC tag? that stores details such as a users credits etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Nexus S can read NFC tag. But its not capable of storing NFC tags as of now. The future OS update of Nexus S will surely have this feature.

Also for your reference,
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg150101.html

This may give you some good idea.